# Envy vs jealousy - has the meaning changed?

Tags: meaning, slang

When I was at school (in the 80's) I learnt that *jealousy* and *envy* meant different things: you are *jealous* if you think someone will take what you have, you are *envious* if you want what they have.

In general usage now they appear to mean the same thing, to the point where *envy* is rarely used while 'jelly' and 'well jel' have become slang (clearly derived from *jealous*) meaning to covet what someone else has.

However, I think a statement like "she had a jealous boyfriend" will still be clearly understood to mean that the boyfriend is excessively possessive of his current girlfriend rather than that that boyfriend is chasing after other girls.

Has the meaning of *jealousy* changed in current usage?

Comment: "you are jealous if you think someone will take what you have" Really?

Comment: You were taught well. Many people apparently were not taught the distinction.  To see whether this misuse has become legit, look up both words in various dictionaries. Some are more descriptivist than others.

Comment: Blessed Geek: yes, really.

Comment: The King James Bible does not seem to hold that opinion.

Comment: When was this opinion of yours invented? Which is completely misaligned with the etymology of the word. Before making any claims, check the etymology first.

Comment: @BlessedGeek - it's not my opinion, it was what I learnt at school. The term *jealousy* as meaning specifically the fear of losing something was definitely commonly understood in England as I was growing up. John Lennon even had a hit single "Jealous Guy" that he wrote as an apology after beating up his wife because he thought she was cheating on him. Everybody understood that he was talking about his own wife and not coveting someone else's.

Comment: That definition must have been colloquial or even pidgin. Jealousy is not the fear of having things taken away. Jealousy is the zealousness and obsession you have for an entity, and then having a fear or apprehension of the possibility that entity no longer providing you the right or facility to exercise that obsession and zeal, but providing it to someone else.

Comment: Jealousy is also the zeal and obsession over an entity, regardless if you currently have the opportunity to express that obsession or zeal.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I would love to see my old school headmaster's face as you describe his language as 'pidgin' ;-) Seriously though - citations and definitions should probably go in an answer rather than comments.

Comment: Sometimes headmasters have the raging jealousy to invent simplistic and imprecise explanations to dissect concepts, as they would rather you had a lesser understanding of than to confuse two words.

Comment: @BlessedGeek it's not just my old headmaster, a [quick google of "jealousy vs envy"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jealousy%20vs%20envy) finds lots of folks that agree with him. Fill out an answer for your definition with citations - the comments aren't really suited to this.

Comment: Certainly "jealous" has a fairly broad set of definitions.

Comment: There may have been a trend in the prevalence of its use in one way or the other. The use that your school headmaster deprecated (desirous of something that one does not have) seems to have existed for a long time: https://books.google.com/books?id=XyJgHqHe71sC&pg=PA213&dq=%22jealous+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgKahUKEwjg-L3LgNrHAhUTNYgKHUclAiM#v=onepage&q=%22jealous%20of%22&f=false, https://books.google.com/books?id=TbECAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22jealous+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBTgKahUKEwjg-L3LgNrHAhUTNYgKHUclAiM#v=onepage&q=%22jealous%20of%22&f=false

Comment: "Envy" and "jealousy" convey the same meaning when coveting somebody's else's belonging. But, "jealousy" also refers to the fear of loosing something(someone) and the means to keep it. –

Comment: I suppose your teacher thought it necessary to teach the difference because there were already people using "jealous" to mean "envious."  Nobody ever taught you the difference between "eat" and "drink," did they?

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between 'envy' and 'jealousy'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41995/whats-the-difference-between-envy-and-jealousy)

Comment: @phoog I'm pretty sure someone _did_ teach me the difference between 'eat' and 'drink', otherwise I wouldn't know what the words mean. I just don't remember it because I was 3. They are in the first batch of words taught to toddlers. 'Jealous' vs 'envious' would be primary school as they're more advanced vocabulary.

Comment: @Keith well maybe so.  I certainly don't remember (explicitly) teaching any of the children in my life the difference between those words; they just picked it up, long before they were three, from the fact that everyone used "drink" with liquids and "eat" with solids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers have done a good job of outlining how "jealousy/jealous" may be distinguished in meaning from "envy/envious." Therefore, I'll focus mainly on the specific question "Has the meaning of *jealousy* changed in current usage?"

### No.

The meaning of *jealousy/jealous* has overlapped with that of *envy/envious* for a very long time; this use (or "misuse," depending on your opinion) of the word greatly predates the 1980s. (On the other hand, it's possible there have been shifts recently in the frequency of use of one versus the other.)

In the Oxford English Dictionary, this falls under definition 4b of
*jealousy*, and there is a list of early examples of the word being used this way:

> 4. The state of mind arising from the suspicion, apprehension, or knowledge of rivalry: 
>    [...]
>    **b.** in respect of success or advantage: Fear of
>      losing some good through the rivalry of another; resentment or
>      ill-will towards another on account of advantage or superiority,
>      possible or actual, on his part; **envy**, grudge. [bolding added]
>
>    - [...]
>    - 1650 R. Stapleton tr. F. Strada *De Bello Belgico* vi. 21 Lest this warrelike Preparation might beget a Ielousy in the minds of princes, his Majesty satisfied them by his Ambassadours.
>    - a1715 Bp. G. Burnet *Hist. Own Time* (1724) I. 208 This drew a jealousy on me from the Bishops.
>    - 1836 W. Irving *Astoria* I. 90 There were feuds between the partners themselves, occasioned..by jealousy of rank.

And here is the relevant definition (with historical examples) of *jealous* from the OED:

> 4. Troubled by the belief, suspicion, or fear that the good which one desires to gain or keep for oneself has been or may be diverted to
>      another; resentful towards another on account of known or suspected
>      rivalry: 
>    [...]
>    **b.** in respect of success or advantage: Apprehensive of losing
>      some desired benefit through the rivalry of another; feeling ill-will
>      towards another on account of some advantage or superiority which he
>      possesses or may possess; grudging, **envious**. [bolding added] Const. of (the person, or the advantage).
>
>    - [...]
>    - 1477 Caxton tr. R. Le Fèvre *Hist. Jason* (1913) 42 Alle were Ialouse of him, But Iason neuer thought on none of them.

The meaning of the word has certainly evolved over time, but this particular evolution occurred centuries ago. I'd also like to note that the same ambiguity appears to apply to the related word in modern French, *jalousie*, as defined by the [Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/jalousie):

> 3. 1501 *jalousie* « envie, dépit que l'on éprouve à l'égard de ce qu'un autre obtient ou possède » (*Chastel de joyeuse destinee* ds *Jardin de plaisance*, XLV).

---

Whether one *should* use the words "jealousy" or "jealous" with this meaning is a separate question; but I hope I've shown clearly that they not only *are*, but they *have been* for quite some time.

Answer (score 4):

The *First International Webster's Dictionary* (1892) defines **jealous** as

> suspicious, envious, anxious.

So *jealousy* could have had the meaning *envy* for over 100 years; the meaning does not seem to have changed.

Answer (score 2):

Being jealous and being envious are two quite different things, yet in common parlance, many people use *jealous* to mean *envious*. It's too bad. I hope the English language does not lose this valuable distinction just because of this frequently heard sloppy usage.

For *jealous*, Merriam-Webster gives: "1.a intolerant of rivalry or unfaithfulness; 1.b disposed to suspect rivalry or unfaithfulness; 2  hostile toward a rival or one believed to enjoy an advantage; 3 vigilant in guarding a possession."

For *envious*, the same source gives: "feeling or showing a desire to have what someone else has."

Comment: Can you add more detail about how and when the meaning has changed, rather than just criticizing the use in "common parlance"?

Comment: I doubt that anyone could pinpoint a "when." In any case, the words are still used by many people with the original meaning, so I don't think we can really say the meaning has truly changed. The word *jealous" has simply acquired the extra meaning "envious," which has become one of its most common usages. If you say, "I envy X," you mean you wish you had something X has or were like X in some way. Many people nowadays express this idea by saying, "I'm jealous of X," but that statement should mean that the speaker does not like it when others show interest in X or covet it.

Comment: What I mean is, do you have any evidence that only one of these definitions is "the original meaning"? For example, what is the earliest attestation of "jealous" for each meaning?

Answer (score 0):

I'm envious of the linguistic skills on display here.

My cat Roxy was jealous when she saw Rosie eating her food.